# Get icons to work with Vue native / React Native - createMaterialBottomTabNavigator

Tags: react-native, vue.js

I'm trying to get the bottom tab navigator to show the icons for `Vue Native`.

I'm new to coding, and it's a little bit confusing for me to understand some bits how `Vue native` and `React native` syntax works. I searched the internet hi and low to find the information that I needed.

I did find some information on the official `React Native` website. 
The `Vue native` official website doesn't contain so much detailed information regarding this.

So, my question is how do I get this to work? The code below spits out an error code when I try to execute it.

Thanks in advance for the help :) 
// Chris

I leave some code snippets below:

```js
<template>
  <app-navigator></app-navigator>
</template>

<script>
import {
  createAppContainer,
  createMaterialBottomTabNavigator,
  createStackNavigator,
} from "vue-native-router";

import Icon from '../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/dist/FontAwesome.js';

import Home from "./screens/HomeScreen.vue";
import Message from "./screens/Message.vue"

const StackNavigator = createMaterialBottomTabNavigator({
  Hem: Home,
  Message: {
      screen: Message,
      navigationOptions: {
        title: 'woop',
        tabBarIcon: ({tintColor})=>{  
              <Icon name="ios-home" color={tintColor} size={25}/>  
          }
      },
    },
});

const AppNavigator = createAppContainer(StackNavigator);

export default {
  components: { Root, AppNavigator },
}
</script>
```

```
{
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "expo": "~36.0.2",
    "expo-font": "~8.0.0",
    "native-base": "^2.13.8",
    "react": "^16.12.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.12.0",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-36.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.5.2",
    "react-native-paper": "^3.4.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^1.4.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.6.0",
    "react-native-web": "~0.11.7",
    "react-navigation-material-bottom-tabs": "^2.1.5",
    "vue-axios": "^2.1.5",
    "vue-native-core": "^0.1.4",
    "vue-native-helper": "^0.1.4",
    "vue-native-router": "^0.1.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.7.7",
    "babel-preset-expo": "~8.0.0",
    "vue-native-scripts": "^0.1.4"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Comment: Could you share what the error is? Quite an important part. Also, could you be more specific with what exactly you want to achieve.

Comment: Hello T. Short! Thanks for the replay. I figure out the error code, by adding: "import * as React from 'react';".  Now i'm trying to get the icons for the bottom tab nav to display by adding this lines of code:

        tabBarIcon: ({tintColor})=>{  
              <Icon name="ios-home" color={tintColor} size={25}/>  
          }

I edit the post ontop for more information.

Thanks agan! // Chris from Sweden :)

Comment: Why are you using React inside of Vue? You should not be mixing the two. Pick one and stick to it or you will be getting these kinds of errors all over the place.

Comment: Okej! I got this to work now.

Well, as i stateted before, i'm trying to use vue native, but the information for it is not so detailed, and Vue native website states this:

Since the app is based on React Navigation v3, you can use most the API’s specified in the react navigation docs at https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/getting-started.html.

Thats way i get confuse some time. So if i want to do it via Vue native, were can i find more information about it? I read the docs from Vue Native website and follow it.
https://vue-native.io/docs/vue-native-router.html

Comment: Added this: 
Message: {
        screen: Message, 
        navigationOptions: {
            tabBarLabel: 'Signout', 
            tabBarIcon: <Icon name="rocket" size={25}/>,
        }
    }

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by adding this:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome';
```

```
  Message: {
          screen: Message, 
          navigationOptions: {
              tabBarLabel: 'Meddelanden', 
              tabBarIcon: <Icon name="rocket" size={25}/>,
          }
      }
```